# How to remove every second element of a SortedDictionary as fast as possible?

Tags: .net, generics, c#-4.0, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I've to remove every second element from a SortedDictionary as fast as possible. The dictionary (`SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>`) can have up to 20'000 elements. So I came up with this solution:

```
try
{
    int loop = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Routes.Remove(Routes.ElementAt(loop).Key);
        loop++;
    }                
}
catch
{
}
```

Is there an easier / better solution than this? 
Will the caught exception have an impact on the performance?

**Edit:** This seems to be a better solution (see comment below):

```
SortedDictionary<string, List<string>> resizedRoutes = new SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>();
bool b = true;
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> route in Routes)
{                                        
    if(b)
    {
        resizedRoutes.Add(route.Key, route.Value);
        b = false;
    }
    else
    {
        b = true;
    }
}
Routes = resizedRoutes;
```

Please edit/comment if you have a better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>I doubt it, because you either need to:</strike>

1. Remove the items, causing the tree to be rebalanced
2. Add the items to a new tree, causing the new tree to be rebalanced

You can't really avoid it, but it might be more efficient to just iterate through them and put them in a `SortedList` if you won't be modifying the data very often.

## Yes:

Iterate through the items, then add every other item them to a new tree, instead of modifying the current tree. That way you'll avoid the cost of calling `ElementAt` every time, which is at *least* logarithmic in an ideal implementation, and **linear** with LINQ's (which is **horrible**, because LINQ has no idea about the implementation of your tree).

As for the exception: Yes, it will have a performance hit. But I have no idea how much that is relative to what you're doing, so it may or may not be significant.
But either way, **you should not be ignoring exceptions**. :)

#### While you're at it:

Might want to take a look at *functional programming*. :)

Comment: I was about to post this answer before your update. Building a new tree would be much cheaper than rebalancing an old tree every removal.

Comment: @drharris: Yeah, I totally didn't notice that `ElementAt` is linear, so I completely ignored it and thought it's fine.

Comment: @Mehrdad Thanks a lot for your answer :-) I think I will build a new tree. Is my assumption correct, that this solution will use more (50% more) memory than my proposal?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, temporarily (more or less).

Answer (score 0):

That is a good enough solution. If an exception is caught, then it will stop removing elements from the dictionary. Maybe rearrange it, like so:

```
int loop = 0;
lock(Routes)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Routes.Remove(Routes.ElementAt(loop).Key);
            loop++;
        }
        catch { break; }
    }
}
```

This will make sure the dictionary cannot be modified while elements are being removed.

Comment: And ***Gulp!***, catch eats another exception! :(

Comment: hmm, interesting, why did you put the try/catch into the while loop?

Comment: So when it tries to remove the element that doesn't exist (at the end), it will break out of the loop.